# Static Resources with Spring Boot 2 and Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm actually having issues with this in **Spring Boot 2.0** and **Spring Security**. I understand that Spring Security now secures *everything*, which inclues static resources, and have implemented the suggested line of code:

```
.requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
```

I've added this to my `WebSecurityConfig`, but it seems like my static resources still cannot be found/mapped/loaded. I'm upgrading from Spring boot 1.5.13 to 2.0.2. Everything is in it's appropriate location.

Anyone else still having this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Works fine for me with Spring Boot 2.0.5, migrating from 1.5.14. Maybe show the full contents of your security configuration?